# How to solve an equality for small values of $m$ and $k$?

Tags: number-theory

Given is the following equality in positive integers:$$1+2^k+\cdots+m^k=(m+1)^k+\cdots +(2m)^k$$we seek to find all the positive integer values for $k$ and $m$ for which the equality holds. I have already proved that there exists a solution for large $m$ and $k=0$ since$$\sum_{i=1}^{m} \left({i\over m}\right)^k=\sum_{i=m+1}^{2m} \left({i\over m}\right)^k\\{1\over m}\sum_{i=1}^{m} \left({i\over m}\right)^k={1\over m}\sum_{i=m+1}^{2m} \left({i\over m}\right)^k$$from the latter equality we obtain $$\int_{0}^{1} x^kdx=\int_{1}^{2} x^kdx\implies k=0$$ how to find other solutions (if there exist any) specially for small values of $m$?

**Edit**

As in ***Ross Millikan's answer***, the RHS is greater that the LHS for $k$ and $m$ being positive integers. I also want to know if the following problem
$$1+2^k+\cdots+m^k=(m+1)^k+\cdots +(m+N)^k$$
 is solvable for any fixed $N\in \Bbb N$ or $$\lim_{m\to \infty} {N\over m}=0.$$ Thanks alot!

Comment: Looks to me like the RHS will be bigger than the LHS.

Answer (score 2):

This is never true unless $k=0.$  If $ k \gt 0,$ the left side is less than $m\cdot m^k$ while the right side is greater than $m\cdot (m+1)^k$, so the right is greater than the left.  If $k=0$ both sides are $m$ and you have equality.